# Why do public wifi networks often have a click screen to join?

Tags: network, wifi, wireless

At many if not most coffeeshops and other public Wi-Fi locations, even though Wi-Fi is free and not password protected, there are click screens with "join" buttons that need to be tapped to access the internet like the one below. Why is this?

[image: Starbucks Wi-Fi Click Screen]

Comment: Why do you think does it say **accept** and connect?

Comment: Alright, I'll state the obvious here. You need to agree with the terms they have setup for their users using the internet. This is most likely done for legal reasons.

Comment: It is to prevent automatic connection to unsecure wifi. This way, you always know when you are connected to unsecured wifi.

Answer (score 5):

[This article](http://www.mbm-law.net/newsletter-articles/wi-fi-hotspots-and-liability-concerns/1229/) has some legal advice for wifi hotspot owners.

It explains that a splash screen is a useful tool to make users explicitly accept the terms and conditions for using the hotspot and thereby reduces potential liability:

> Consult your attorneys before setting up a Wi-Fi Hotspot at your business location. The following are some steps a business owner can consider in setting up a Wi-Fi HotSpot to reduce potential liability:
>
> [...]
>
> (b)   The Wi-Fi HotSpot access point can contain a use agreement and disclaimer (sometimes called a “splash page”) that requires the user to click through an agreement before enabling access;
>
> (c)   The use agreement and disclaimer can disclose appropriate terms and conditions of use, which prohibit and do not authorize, for example, illegal activity, copyright violations, pornographic or corrupt content, spam, solicitations, advertising, or use of the service by unsupervised minors.